# Hibernate @Id @GeneratedValue annotation doesn't recognise increment ID generated by DB2 Database

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, hibernate-annotations, object-persistence

Inserting a second record using Hibernate 3 into DB2 v9.x where a column has a Unique primary key column Id generated by DB2 doesn't work with persisting my Hibernate entity.

Inserting the first record works fine, however unless I manually increment and set the value using the setter no more records can be persisted. I have tried commenting out @GeneratedValue....am I using this correctly? I do not want Hibernate to auto increment the Id column, I want it to use the incremented ID generated by DB2 itself to insert the next row. Thanks:)

This is my code:

```
private short APLSEQNUM;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "MRT_APLSEQNUM")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public short getAPLSEQNUM() {
    return APLSEQNUM;
}
```

The contrainst added in DB2 create table script to generate the Id:

```
"MRT_APLSEQNUM" SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (  START WITH +1  
INCREMENT BY +1  
MINVALUE +1  
MAXVALUE +32767  
NO CYCLE  
CACHE 20  
NO ORDER )
```

This is the exception:

> Hibernate: insert into RPS.TMRT (MRT_APRNUM, MRT_CHKLOC, MRT_DPTCDE, MRT_FUNCDE, MRT_MDCNUM, MRT_MDCRSLCDE, MRT_MDCRSLDTE, MRT_OCCCDE, MRT_QIDNO, MRT_REGDTE, MRT_REMARK, MRT_SECCDE, MRT_SMP, MRT_USRID, MRT_VISNUM, MRT_APLYER, MRT_APLSEQNUM, MRT_ACMPNUM) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   15-Mar-2011 17:37:44 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
>   WARNING: SQL Error: -803, SQLState: 23505
>   15-Mar-2011 17:37:44 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
>   SEVERE: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -803, SQLSTATE: 23505, SQLERRMC: 1;RPS.TMRT
>   15-Mar-2011 17:37:44 org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
>   SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [qa.gov.moi.rps.db.entity.Medical_MRT]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2272)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2665)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:60)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
>       at qa.gov.moi.rps.db.helper.MedicalHelper.create(MedicalHelper.java:74)
>       at qa.gov.moi.rps.db.helper.MedicalHelper.main(MedicalHelper.java:285)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
>   Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -803, SQLSTATE: 23505, SQLERRMC: 1;RPS.TMRT
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.fg.d(fg.java:1340)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gb.k(gb.java:351)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gb.a(gb.java:60)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.w.a(w.java:52)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wb.c(wb.java:213)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.ab(gg.java:1779)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.d(gg.java:2324)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.W(gg.java:457)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.executeUpdate(gg.java:440)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2252)
>       ... 18 more
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while commiting the transaction
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
>       at qa.gov.moi.rps.db.helper.MedicalHelper.create(MedicalHelper.java:74)
>       at qa.gov.moi.rps.db.helper.MedicalHelper.main(MedicalHelper.java:285)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [qa.gov.moi.rps.db.entity.Medical_MRT]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2272)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2665)
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:60)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
>       ... 7 more
>   Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -803, SQLSTATE: 23505, SQLERRMC: 1;RPS.TMRT
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.fg.d(fg.java:1340)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gb.k(gb.java:351)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gb.a(gb.java:60)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.w.a(w.java:52)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.wb.c(wb.java:213)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.ab(gg.java:1779)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.d(gg.java:2324)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.W(gg.java:457)
>       at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gg.executeUpdate(gg.java:440)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2252)
>       ... 18 more

Comment: Have you tried using @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) or @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)? Not sure if either will actually help...

Answer (score 3):

Use  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Answer (score 0):

here's what we did :

we created a sequence in DB2 :
[image]

in the hibernate mapping file :

```
<id name="idClass" column="IDROW" >
    <generator class="sequence">
      <param name="sequence">SIDFINANCEMENT</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Works in a clustered environment where many instances need to get a sequence and the sequence generated is unique.